# static site + wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

I have a company website that was built with mostly static html with a bit of PHP for form submissions. I set it up to use nginx + php5-fpm. After that we did a partnet company site and used wordpress. So part of the marketing group saw some of the abilities to leverage wordpress for more dynamic content like news, events, shows, etc. So they want that with the ability for them to easy post information on their own for our site. And they want something quickly.

I don't have the time to redo the website in wordpress right now. They were asking if I could just use wordpress for that part of the site. I know this should be possible, but I'm starting to think it is going to be a bit more difficult then I initially thought.

Since we are using nginx/php5-fpm and wordpress uses apache and I don't think it uses php-fpm. So is this possible? Could I leverage nginx adn php-fpm instead? This is on a VPS.

Thanks

Comment: Yes it is possible. [Digital ocean tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-wordpress-with-nginx-on-ubuntu-12-04) setting up wordpress on a VPS using ngnix.  Wordpress doesn't care what is serving the pages or how php is being run, from apache or ngnix, it is all abstracted from it

Comment: As above, yes you can run wordpress on nginx, and once its up and running you can access wordpress functions from withing your existing php files by including `wp-blog-header.php` at the top of those files

Comment: OK thanks. I assume this would be better then trying to run apache alongside nginx (additional config and resources).